# $\inf m_*(O)$ for Open Set $O$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to understand $\inf m_*(O)$ for Open Set $O$ correctly since it took some time for me to straighten out the infimum in $m_*(O)$.

In the Exterior Measure section by Stein and Shakarchi (2009), they state:

> "If $E\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, then $m_*(E)=\inf m_*(O)$ where the infimum is taken over all open sets $O$ containing $E$."

*My Question:*

1. Is my understanding of $\inf m_*(O)$ correct?

$$\inf m_*(O)=\inf\{m_*(O):E\subset O\}$$
$$\inf m_*(O)=\inf\{\inf\{\sum_j|Q_j|:O\subset\bigcup_j Q_j,Q_j^s \text{ are closed cubes}\}:E\subset O\}$$
Thus,

$\inf m_*(O)$ is the infimum of the set of the greatest lower bounds of open sets that each contain $E$.

2. Is my interpretation of the above observation correct?

You start with $E$. Consider a collection of open sets that contain E. To obtain the outer measure $E$, for each open set containing E, find the outer measure itself by the usual method of fitting the small closed cubes. We put these $m_*(O)^s$, which are numbers, into a set and take an infimum of this set. This should equal to $m_*(E)$. In other words, you are looking a sequence of nested open covers that contain $E$ and for each of this, you can obtain the exterior measure. But we want to find the infimum in this sequence, then it would be exactly the outer measure of $E$.

3. From the above, if we have a negligible volume set $E$, how do we infer if $m_*(E)=0$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists an open set $O$ with $E\subset O$ and $m_*(O)\leq\epsilon$? In other words, how do we infer the existence of such open set from the above statement?

Reference:
$\textit{Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces}$. Elias M. Stein, Rami Shakarchi. Princeton University Press, 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You observation $1,2$ are correct.

For $3$ let $E$ with $m_*(E)=0$ and $\epsilon >0$

Then exists a sequence $Q_n$ of closed cubes,such that $E \subset \bigcup_n Q_n$ and $$m_*(E) \leq \sum_n |Q_n| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

For every $Q_n$ we can find an open cube $A_n \supset Q_n$ such that $|A_n| \leq |Q_n|+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}$

Then $E \subset \bigcup_n A_n$

and so for the open set  $O:=\bigcup_n A_n$ we have $$m_*(O) \leq \sum_n|A_n| \leq \sum_n(|Q_n|+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was great.

Comment: So the idea here is that when you begin with the set $E$, you first cover them with bunch of closed cubes, and then for each cube, create an open cubes that covers these cubes individually. Take the union of these open cubes and you get an open set that covers the original set $E$, and from that we can show this open cover is arbitrarily close to $E$. But why do we go through all these steps. Why is it NOT valid to say, there is just an open cover that is arbitrarily close to the exterior measure of $E$ to begin with? It seems a detour.

Comment: I took closed cubes because you of your definition in your post..its a matter of definition...you can define the exterior measure with closed,open,or half-open cubes